# Cookies Blocked on Bitnami Wordpress Multisite

Tags: dns, cookies, wordpress

I've installed the AMI from Bitnami with the Multisite as an EC2 instance.
Configured everything, but when I try to access /wp-admin using chrome or Edge, it gives an error:

> Error: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

I'm using the default EC2 host as I don't have access to change DNS records at the moment. The hostname is something like: ec2-22-452-71-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com

If I use Firefox it works correctly. I have tried clearing the cache, running in Incognito mode, and nothing worked at all.

Can someone help me or give a hint? I've found a lot of bugs reported about this error with multiples fixes involving wp-config.php edition, tried them all already.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, I really don't know but it works.
The issue is with the hostname that AWS gives us.

Steps to fix the issue:

1. Register a SIMPLER hostname (HOSTS file or DNS), like: 22.33.44.55 simpler.domain.com
2. SSH into the server and execute: `sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --machine_hostname simpler.domain.com`
3. ...
4. PROFIT!

Maybe the issue it's related to "-" characters on the hostname that AWS EC2 gives us, otherwise I don't know what could be. I just know it WORKS!

Hope it can help someone! :-)